# What are the .cache files in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm working in Visual Studio and am seeing all these binary files with .cache extensions.

For example, XXXGenerateResource.Cache, DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache etc.

Can anyone explain what these files are? What they are used for etc? I've scoured this web site and the entire internet and they are not not explained anywhere,

Can anyone help?

Comment: Undocumented, it can sort-of be reverse-engineered from the MSBuild target files.  It does get mentioned in the MSDN article for the GenerateResource.StateFile property.  One of the hardest things that a build has to do is figuring out that nothing needs to be done.  Which everybody expects to be *really* fast.  But it is quite expensive, on a large solution it has to check *hundreds* of files and that can seriously drag on a spindle drive.  So it preserves what it found out in the .cache files, useful to make the *next* build much faster.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I guess I've abandoned this one. I do not know what they are for. I delete them and VS recreates them. it's peculiar, as if they're not needed at all. in fact, it seems you can repeatedly delete the .cache file, go about your work in VS and the IDE just nicely and very gracefully recreates them